# cpu TLB - tlb full -> next entry is a miss?

Tags: x86, x86-64, intel, cpu-architecture, tlb

#### Context:

x86_64, intel core 2 duo.

I searched through the 3 intel doc volumes, and may have missed the right section, hence the question.

A tlb can have up to 4096 entries, that is a lot in my book. But that is not that much in a SMP system after all. Especially if the tlb is not flushed thanks to the tag bit -> almost full all the time.

Imagine the case in which you have your memory properly mapped throughout the 4 page tables. Imagine that you have more than 4096 entries (i know..), and that, obviously, it is too much for the tlb.

I know that x86 doesn't automatically generate page fault on tlb miss.

#### Question:

Should I be assured that the mmu will walk the page tables and replace one of the entries **automatically** (since it is already correctly mapped) ?

It would make sense, since there is nothing more to do on the operating system side, the memory is already mapped.

Thanks

Comment: It probably uses pLRU bits on the TLB entries https://patents.google.com/patent/US20100306499

Comment: See [What happens after a L2 TLB miss?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32256250) for details *other* than the eviction mechanism / replacement policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, on a TLB miss the MMU will walk the page table and replace an existing TLB entry if there is no empty space available to hold the new entry.

A TLB miss will only result in a page fault if the page is not present in memory.

Comment: Thanks Craig for confirming my assumption :)