# should OOO machine broadcast the speculative load to functional unit?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I believe this is old question and the answer should be somewhere but I cannot find it.

In out of order (OOO) execution machine, assume a load is done speculatively and a wrong data has been read from a l1 cache. At the same time, there is a instruction in the integer ALU reservation station waiting for the load value.

such as

```
store 5 to address 300
// some other instructions
load address 300 to r1
r2 = r1 + r3
```

In this situation, what is the interaction between LSU (load store unit) and RS (reservation station). Which one in the below is common?

1. the LSU broadcast the wrong r1 value read from address 300 (hoping the the address speculation is correct) so that the instruction (`r2=r1+r3`) can be executed. Later, when LSU learn the misspeculation and replay load and addition before the commit.
2. Be conservative and do not broadcast r2 value from the load. This way, there is no need for the replay for the (`r2=r1+r3`)

I think the option 1 is the common approach (year 2023) because option 2 is not so much aligned with the idea of OOO (exploit parallelism as much as possible).

Comment: You wrote "r2 value from the load" in two places, but the load was into r1.  Or do you mean the r2 result from the add?

Comment: See discussion in comment on [How does Load Store Queue work in the presence of MSHR?](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/116455842) and [About the RIDL vulnerabilities and the "replaying" of loads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56188631) (note the corrections mentioned at the top) re: Intel CPUs optimistically sending uops to execution units in anticipation of an L1d hit, and then an L2 hit if that didn't happen.  Presumably this is because they're trying to save a cycle of latency vs. waiting to see if the load produced anything ready for use.

Comment: There are also cases like Meltdown, where a load that will fault if it reaches retirement (because of user vs. kernel permission bits on the PTE/TLB entry) still produces data from an L1d, allowing speculative execution of dependent uops along that mis-speculated path.  https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/05/meltdown-microarchitecture/ / [Why are AMD processors not/less vulnerable to Meltdown and Spectre?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/177101)

Comment: @NateEldredge I corrected the typo. I mean r1, an operand for the addition.

Comment: Intel CPUs dynamically predict whether or not a load forwards from any recent stores whose addresses aren't known. https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2014/01/x86-memory-disambiguation/. On mispredict, a full `machine_clears.memory_ordering` event. (In your sequence of events, the load would have to run before the store-address execution unit wrote the address into the store buffer, otherwise there'd be no need for speculation.  (Perhaps the store-address op got scheduled to a port with a longer queue, or the 300 was the result of a chain of calculations, vs. the load address being ready sooner..))

Comment: I'd guess that many other microarchitectures are similar to what Intel Sandybridge-family does, but I don't know.  Nuking all younger instructions in the pipeline on mis-speculation allows speculative exec to remove uops from the RS as they're dispatched (Interl terminology) to execution units, as usual.  And for chains of dependent work to happen while waiting to confirm the prediction.  Replays of instructions dependent on loads only happen on Intel CPUs when the load doesn't end up producing a value at all, e.g. on cache miss, rather than producing a wrong value.