# What happens on a TLB miss? Is pipelined stalled? Exception raised?

Tags: caching, tlb

Since a TLB miss means we have to traverse the page table, does TLB miss mean we need to stall the instruction pipeline?

Comment: [What happens after a L2 TLB miss?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32256250) discusses mostly modern x86.  It also mentions software TLB handling like on MIPS where a TLB miss is indeed a fault, unlike on most other ISAs where a fault only happens after a hardware page walk fails. (page fault).  An iTLB miss would stall the front-end but out-of-order exec can continue around dTLB misses and even page-walks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens after a L2 TLB miss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256250/what-happens-after-a-l2-tlb-miss)