# Can a TLB miss be reported as a frontend stall in the CPU by the PMU counters?

Tags: caching, x86, cpu-architecture

I run a really tiny program with different memory access patterns and get confusing PMC readings from Linux `perf`:

- when it access an overall small region of memory, there are many L1 cache misses, a large % of CPU cycles stalled in the backend, negligible % of frontend stalls
- but when the program accesses a somewhat large memory region (like 512 8-byte words, separated by 1024 bytes; so overall 512KB of memory), `perf` reports many L1 misses, but practically *no backend stalls*, and a large % of *frontend* stalls. (Also, the instructions/cycle & the speed of the program decrease more than when there are only backend stalls.)

I was not expecting *frontend* stalls. The whole program is a tiny loop with few `mov`s. All instructions decoding should be cached:

```
       │       lea      _end,%rsi
       │140:┌─→mov      %rbp,%rdx
       │    │
       │    │  lea      data_in,%rax
       │    │
       │14a:│  mov      (%rax),%rcx  <-- mem accesses, i.e. address calculation
       │    │memcpy():
 96.31 │    │  mov      %rcx,(%rdx)
       │    │
  1.81 │    │  add      $0x400,%rax
  0.20 │    │  add      $0x400,%rdx  <-- here 0x400=1024 defines the memory access pattern
  1.12 │    │  cmp      %rsi,%rax
  0.57 │    │↑ jne      14a
       │    │  sub      $0x1,%edi
       │    └──jne      140
```

Also, as far as I understand, all the address calculations (including TLB cache things) happen in the *backend* of the CPU, in the memory subsystem. So, it seems confusing when a change in the program memory access pattern shows up as *frontend stalls* with practically no stalls in the backend. But the measured frontend stalls do seem to correlate with TLB misses, both L1 and L2 TLB cache. So, I wonder if a TLB miss could somehow be counted as a frontend stall by the PMU?

For example, could the backend spend so much time on page-walking, that it also stalls the frontend? Then, why the PMU counters don't report *both* frontend and backend stalled? Maybe, the point is that while the backend is computing the addresses and walking pages, it is *not considered as really "stalled"*? Then it just stalls the frontend because the walking takes so long that the instruction pipeline gets filled up.

Also, how does the virtual memory structure cooperate with the micro-op cache in the frontend instruction decoder? [Here](https://chipsandcheese.com/2023/08/04/sandy-bridge-setting-intels-modern-foundation/) on Intel Sandy Bridge, they mention something like: "micro-op cache ...[is] virtually addressed, meaning that program addresses don’t have to be translated to do a micro-op cache lookup". So, it means the frontend just returns decoded instructions with *virtual addresses* in them, for the backend's memory subsystem to turn into real addresses. Therefore, a TLB miss or anything memory-related like that does not directly affect the frontend and its micro-op cache?

My CPU is AMD Zen 2, Ryzen 5 PRO 4650G.

Comment: related question with less details and no answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76060748/what-happens-on-a-tlb-miss-is-pipelined-stalled-exception-raised

Comment: dTLB misses should be back-end stalls, not front-end. Like all modern high-performance CPUs, Zen 2 has a separate iTLB (https://7-cpu.com/cpu/Zen2.html), so dTLB misses shouldn't be evicting iTLB entries and causing iTLB misses.  *That* could explain front-end stalls, but dTLB misses can't.  (*[What happens after a L2 TLB miss?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32256250)* does have an answer, but it's not specific to this issue.  The simple Q&A you linked in your comment is probably a duplicate of it.)

Comment: Have you checked for errata for the performance counters on your CPU?  Sometimes there are CPU bugs that make them count differently from what one would expect.  And BTW, a "front-end stall" normally means that there aren't any uops ready to issue/alloc/rename from the front-end to the back-end.  e.g. events like Intel `idq_uops_not_delivered.core` which counts number of issue slots for uops not delivered to the RAT for renaming, when the back-end was not stalled.  i.e. when the back-end being full wasn't the reason it didn't rename the max number of uops that cycle.

Comment: the CPU is family 0x17 model 0x60. It looks like no revision guide [was published by AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/search/documentation/hub.html#q=Family%2017h&sortCriteria=%40amd_release_date%20descending&f-amd_document_type=Revision%20Guides) for this model. In models 0x00-0F and 30-3F they do say "some PMC may overcount", but nothing on TLB & frontend stalls. It could also be incorrectly defined in Linux' perf, couldn't it?

Comment: I ran the same program on Intel Xeon 4116. Unfortunately perf doesn't have the general frontend|backend stall events for this CPU. There are many more precise ones, though. But, according to perf, it does not get TLB misses so easily. And it seems like the program slows down simply when it misses L2 cache more.

Comment: *it means the frontend just returns decoded instructions with virtual addresses in them, for the backend's memory subsystem to turn into real addresses* - no, it means address-translation only has to happen during initial fetch/decode, when populating the uop cache from the legacy-decode part of the front-end.  Like a VIVT (virtually indexed virtually tagged) data cache, a uop-cache hit implicitly means the virtual address is valid.  Conversely, the uop cache has to be invalidated for pages whose TLB entries are invalidated.  That's how Intel's uop caches work, IDK about AMD.